# How to express "two objects are wrongly placed on each other's place"

Tags: word-request

I want to know how to express the situation of two objects wrongly being placed on each other's place.

For example, there are two illustrations on a book, say fig1 and fig2, however fig1 is wrongly placed on the position that fig2 should have been, fig2 is also wrongly placed on the position that fig1 should have been. Is there any way I can describe this situation briefly in English?

Comment: In addition to the answers already posted, you might say the illustrations were interchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If I tell someone my phone number is 1234 and they write down 1324, I would say they have **transposed** the two middle digits. 'Swapped' is an informal equivalent you could use in conversation.

[Transpose (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transpose)

Answer (score 0):

I would describe the objects as "(accidentally) swapped". The implication is that the objects have swapped position